# Mutable and immutable collection classes are the same kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection, collections, jvm, mutable

When using reflection to investigate collection classes, mutable and immutable classes for the same type are referentially equal.

**Why is this the case?**

```
    @Test
    fun demonstrate_mutableAndImmutableClassesAreTheSame() {
        println("(MutableIterable::class === Iterable::class) = ${(MutableIterable::class === Iterable::class)}")
        println("(MutableCollection::class === Collection::class) = ${(MutableCollection::class === Collection::class)}")
        println("(MutableList::class === List::class) = ${(MutableList::class === List::class)}")
        println("(MutableSet::class === Set::class) = ${(MutableSet::class === Set::class)}")
        println("(MutableMap::class === Map::class) = ${(MutableMap::class === Map::class)}")
        println("(MutableMap.MutableEntry::class === Map.Entry::class) = ${(MutableMap.MutableEntry::class === Map.Entry::class)}")
    }
```

prints

> (Iterable::class === MutableIterable::class) = true
> (Collection::class === MutableCollection::class) = true
> (List::class === MutableList::class) = true
> (Set::class === MutableSet::class) = true

Comment: In the platform (JVM) both are the same. You cannot make overload of those types because they are the same at runtime as well see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015248/kotlin-make-constructor-of-data-class-accept-both-list-and-mutablelist-but-store). The docs mention this as well [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types)

Comment: Might be worth noting that this is only true when `kotlin-reflect` is included as a dependency (otherwise all results are `false`.) This also does not apply to Kotlin/JS (and presumably also native, but I haven't tested that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collection` and `MutableCollection` are mapped to the same java.util.Collection class (mapped-types), so from POV of JVM (after compilation at runtime) that they are the same.

If you decompile the code you've written, you'll get this (I've decompiled it using Kotlin Bytecode generated by Intellij):

**Kotlin:**

```kotlin
fun demonstrate_mutableAndImmutableClassesAreTheSame() {
    println("(MutableCollection::class === Collection::class) = ${(MutableCollection::class === Collection::class)}")
}
```

**Java:**

```java
import kotlin.jvm.internal.Reflection;

// class declaration
public static final void demonstrate_mutableAndImmutableClassesAreTheSame() {
    String var0 = "(MutableCollection::class === Collection::class) = " + (Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinClass(Collection.class) == Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinClass(Collection.class));
    boolean var1 = false;
    System.out.println(var0);
}
```

References:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types
- [(imutable collection is mutable) returns true in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53951277/11377112)
- [Kotlin make constructor of data class accept both List and MutableList but store a mutable instance of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62015248/11377112)